# How to find $[S_6:H]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Consider $S_6$.
>   Consider $H=\{\sigma\in S_6:\sigma(4)=4\}$ .
>
> Show that $H$ is a subgroup of $S_6$.
>   Find $[S_6:H]$.

I did the first question.Obviuously $e\in H$ and if $\sigma_1,\sigma_2\in H$ then $\sigma_1\sigma_2(4)=\sigma_1(\sigma_2(4))=4$.

Also  $\sigma_1^{-1}(4)=4$.

Hence $H$ will be a subgroup of $S_6$.

But how to find $[S_6:H]$?

I was thinking of finding a homomorphism $\phi$ from $S_6$ to $H$.

If $\sigma(4)=4 $ then we take $\phi(\sigma)=\sigma$.

If $\sigma(4)\neq 4 $,I am wondering how should I define $\phi(\sigma)$.

Is there any way to define $\phi(\sigma)$?

I need some help.

Comment: You're over-thinking it.  Just find $|S_6|$ and $|H|$.

Comment: @David,yes it was so easy,i misjudged it ,thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

There is a natural action of $S_6$ on $6$ numbers, and $H$ is exactly the stabilizer of one of those letters. This action is of course transitive, so by the orbit-stabilizer theorem, $6|H|=|S_6|$.

Comment: This seems like the intended solution for am exercise in a group theory course.

Answer (score 0):

As we know, $\mid S_6\mid=6!$.  By similar reasoning, $\mid H\mid=5!$ (if $4$ is fixed you are permuting $5$ numbers).  Thus the index is $6$.